# Silverman AEC: Corollary IV.4.4.

Tags: commutative-algebra, elliptic-curves, formal-power-series, formal-groups

In Silverman's *Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves*, Corollary IV.4.4 states that (for an arbitrary ring $R$),

> Let $\mathcal{F}/R$ be a formal group and let $p\in \mathbb{Z}$ be a prime.
> There are power series $f(T), g(T)\in R[\![ T ]\!]$ with $f(0) = g(0) = 0$ such that $[p](T) = pf(T) + g(T^p).$

In the proof, Silverman needs that if the formal derivative $[p]'(T)$ is in $pR[\![T]\!]$, then every term $aT^n$ in the series $[p](T)$ is such that either $a\in pR$ or $p\mid n$.

**Question 1.** But I think that this argument is valid if and only if $p$ is a prime in $R$. Could anyone tell me why Silverman's proof is valid in general? (I did not find this in his errata of AEC.) Thanks in advance!

Below is a screenshot of the proof: [image: Silverman's proof]

**Question 2. (if the proof does not work in general)** Silverman later uses this IV.4.4 in the proof of Theorem IV.6.1 and in Remark IV.7.1, where for Theorem IV.6.1 the assumption is that $R$ is a DVR and $p$ equals the characteristic of the residue field of $R$, and for Remark IV.7.1 the assumption is that $R$ is a ring of characteristic $p>0$.
Is it valid to apply IV.4.4 to them under their respective assumptions?

**My thoughts.**
I think when for IV.6.1 if $R=\mathbb{Z}_p$, then $p$ is a prime in $R$ and it is fine. For a general DVR $R$, if I know that the characteristic of its residue field $R/\mathfrak{m}$ is a prime (or $0$) in $R$, then it is fine in general.
As for IV.7.1, where $p=\mathrm{char}R$, I think we need that $R$ is a domain so that $p=0$ is a ''prime'' in $R$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will become obvious if you write down $[p](T) = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty a_n T^n$ and then $[p]'(T) = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty na_nT^{n - 1}$.

What we have is that $na_n \in pR$ for each $n$. There are two cases: either $p\mid n$, or $p$ is prime to $n$.

In the second case, there exist $q, r \in \Bbb Z$ such that $pq + nr = 1$ and hence $a_n = pqa_n + r(na_n) \in pR$.

Comment: Many thanks! I did write down the power series, but the idea of using the Euclidean algorithm did not come to my mind.